# Стрим с вебкамеры

Tags: python, opencv, udp, rtp, видео

Приветствую!

Встала задача организовать стрим с вебкамеры через локальную сеть. Поток я предполагаю открывать в VLC, но вот чем его передавать? Камера полключена к маку (если нужно, поставлю ноут с виндой). Я думал захватывать видео c OpenCV (у них есть модуль под питон, который мне нравится больше, но писать на С — не проблема для меня) и передавать кадры через RTP, но не пойму, что делать со звуком: может ли opencv захватить его? Кроме того я не нашел нормального примера передачи видео через RTP.

Comment: А зачем реализовывать на таком низком уровне? Поставьте какой-нибудь видеосервер и все.

Comment: @Кудрин Сергей, На самом деле реализовывать на таком уровне просто интересно. Кроме того на видеосервер банально нет денег (вы же об отдельной железке говорите?). А вот какая-нибудь софтиночка  значительно облегчит мне жизнь, так как мне не прийдется думать о сроках. Что посоветуете?

Comment: используйте ffmpeg, правда он под маком не работает с камерами нормально (точнее не работает совсем). Но на линуксе и винде работает отлично.

Но для мака есть кучка программ, бесплатных, которые передают видео.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи тоже используй **VLC**.

Меню Медиа - Передавать - Устройство захвата - кнопка Поток.
Выбери назначение потока какой-нибудь RTP и вещай.

Всё это также можно сделать с коммандной строки `cvlc`.

Answer (score 0):

А что использовать тот же мессенджер (что то на подобие ICQ) нельзя?

создаем видео конференцию, и все(ну как в скайпе).

преимущество:

1. программ готовых много.
2. протоколов реализации много.
3. документации и гайдов по написании на любом языке(от Асемблера до ... Яva).

П.С. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP

замечу что даже Facebook упоминается, так что это вам не хухры-мухры...